# building a color wheel in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am just learning some details about html5 canvas, and in the progress, I am trying to build a simple color wheel by wedges (build a 1 degree wedge at a time and add it up to 360 degree). However, I am getting some weird marks on the gradient as shown in the following image:

[image: wierd color marks].

Here is the fiddle that produced the colorwheel: http://jsfiddle.net/53JBM/

In particular, this is the JS code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("picker");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;
var counterClockwise = false;

for(var angle=0; angle<=360; angle+=1){
    var startAngle = (angle-1)*Math.PI/180;
    var endAngle = angle * Math.PI/180;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = 'hsl('+angle+', 100%, 50%)';
    context.fill();
}
```

If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to accomplish what I am attempting to do it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this enough to you, please check

```
var startAngle = (angle-2)*Math.PI/180;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this works and -1 doesn't? I would love to know the underlying reason.

Comment: Actually you have to do like this     var startAngle = (angle-1)*Math.PI/180;
    var endAngle = (angle+1) * Math.PI/180;

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean by co-ordinates of arcs, what i want is for it to sweep 1 degree wedge, and paint many such wedges right? It seems what you are doing is to have 2 degrees per wedge and covering up half of current one with the next one. My understanding is probably not correct at all, if you could enlighten me where I am going wrong it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you just add this context.stroke(); next to your context.arc(), and you will come to know what arc is doing, and how color is filled and what is change of co-ordinates in arcs doing..

Answer (score 7):

Try this it looks great.
Thanks by the way this is exactly what I was trying to make.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("picker");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;
var counterClockwise = false;

for(var angle=0; angle<=360; angle+=1){
    var startAngle = (angle-2)*Math.PI/180;
    var endAngle = angle * Math.PI/180;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
    context.closePath();
    var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, radius);
 gradient.addColorStop(0,'hsl('+angle+', 10%, 100%)');
 gradient.addColorStop(1,'hsl('+angle+', 100%, 50%)');
    context.fillStyle = gradient;
    context.fill();
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="picker"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach, just for the color

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("picker");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 50;
var thickness = 0.6;

for(var angle=0; angle<=360; angle+=1){
    var startAngle = (angle-2)*Math.PI/180;
    var endAngle = angle * Math.PI/180;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, (1-thickness/2)*radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    context.lineWidth = thickness*radius;
    context.strokeStyle = 'hsl('+angle+', 100%, 50%)';
    context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="picker"></canvas>
</body>
```

**Edit:** full project here: https://github.com/dersimn/jquery-colorwheel